# Type Conversion issue Flutter - Convert from Future<List<Dog>?> to List<Dog>

Tags: flutter, dart, future, dart-null-safety, sqflite

Below is the method to retrieve a list of data from local sqlite table:

```
Future<List<Dog>?> retriveDogs() async {
    return await _dbHelper?.dogs();
  }
```

and you can check dogs() method as below :

```
Future<List<Dog>> dogs() async {
final db = await database;
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('dogs');
return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  return Dog(
    id: maps[i]['id'],
    name: maps[i]['name'],
    age: maps[i]['age'],
  );
});

}
```

I want to display list in my log or via print statement.
So, I have done as below :

```
print(" >>> "+retriveDogs().toString());
```

But it gives me as :
**>> Instance of 'Future<List?>** after print..

How can I get the complete list of Dogs ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `retriveDogs` can retune null value. You can pass empty list for null cases like.

```dart
Future<List<Dog>> retriveDogs() async {
    return await _dbHelper?.dogs()??[];
  }
```

and to get data from future, you can use `await` or `.then`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final data = await retriveDogs();
  print(data.toString());
},
```

```dart
retriveDogs().then((value) => print(value));
```

Comment: That's fine. The Question is how can I get complete list of dogs? In print it giving me >>> Instance of 'Future<List<Dog>>'

Comment: use `await` before it, or with `.then`